# Symfony3 - getErrors is always empty from Ajax form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

I am currently working on a form validation in ajax. (I use Symfony3)

I would like to be able to edit the information of a user in ajax. My ajax query works fine until my controller, which fails to pass the function `$form->isValid()`.

I have looked at several post and tutorial but I have the impression that the operation is different for version 3 (or maybe I just make​ ​errors ^^')

This is my function to edit my user in ajax :

```
public function editMemberAction(Request $request, User $entity)
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $form = $this->createForm('ProjectBundle\Form\User\UserType', $entity,array('validation_groups' => array('Default'), 'organisation' => array()));
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $passwordOriginal = $entity->getPassword();
                $plainPassword = $form->get('plainPassword')->getData();
                if (!empty($plainPassword)) {
                    $encoder = $this->get('security.password_encoder');
                    $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($entity, $plainPassword);

                    $entity->setPassword($encoded);
                } else {
                    $entity->setPassword($passwordOriginal);
                }

                $entity->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')));
                $entity->setUpdatedBy($this->getUser());

                $em->persist($entity);
                $em->flush();
                return new Response(json_encode(array('success' => true)));
            } else {
                dump($form->getErrors());die();
                return new Response(json_encode(array(
                    'res'    => false,
                    'errors' => $this->getErrorsAsArray($form))));
            }

        }
        return new Response();
    }
```

**Even if I correctly filled out my form, I will go all the time into the else**, and when I want to view the errors, I always get an empty error array.

The current dump shows me a huge array like this:

[image: My dump array]

But when I see in the 'error' section at the bottom of the table, the error variables are empty:

[image: errors array]

My UserType form :

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('lastname',null,array('required' => true))
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('gender',null,array('required'=>true))
            ->add('organisationMember',null,array(
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => $options['organisation'],
                'group_by' => 'type_organisation',
                'placeholder' => 'Choisissez votre organisation'
            ))
            ->add('job')
            ->add('mobile')
            ->add('phone')
            ->add('alert_failure')
            ->add('alert_full')
            ->add('alert_other')
            ->add('plainPassword', TextType::class, array('required' => false))
            ->add('email')
            ->add('profile', null, array(
                'required' => true,
                'placeholder' => 'Choose an organisation !',
            ));
    }
```

And my user entity (just a part) with Assert :

```
<?php

namespace ProjectBundle\Entity\User;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use ProjectBundle\Entity\Gender\Gender;
use ProjectBundle\Entity\Organisation\Organisation;
use ProjectBundle\Entity\Traits\BlameableEntity;
use ProjectBundle\Entity\User\Profile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntityValidator;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ProjectBundle\Repository\User\UserRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;
    use BlameableEntity;
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"ajout"})
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"registration"})
     * @Assert\Length(groups={"registration"},
     *      min = 2,
     *      max = 254,
     *      minMessage = "Votre mot de passe doit comporter au minimum {{ limit }} caractères.",
     *      maxMessage = "Votre mot de passe doit comporter au maximum {{ limit }} caractères."
     * )
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $plainPassword;


    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     * @Assert\Email(
     *     message = "L'adresse mail '{{ value }}' n'est pas valide.",
     *     checkMX = true
     * )
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=100, nullable = true)
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=100, nullable = true)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="job", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $job;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=15)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mobile", type="string", length=15)
     */
    private $mobile;
```

Even if I check only for the mobile field for example :

```
dump($form['email']->getErrors()->__toString());
```

It is empty ..

So i tried to use function like :

```
private function getErrors($form)
    {
        $errors = array();

        if ($form instanceof \Symfony\Component\Form\Form) {

            // соберем ошибки элемента
            foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {

                $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
            }

            // пробежимся под дочерним элементам
            foreach ($form->all() as $key => $child) {
                /** @var $child \Symfony\Component\Form\Form */
                if ($err = $this->getErrors($child)) {
                    $errors[$key] = $err;
                }
            }
        }

        return $errors;
    }
```

But the errors array is always empty again ..

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: Did you try `$form->isSubmitted()` instead of `$form->isValid()`?

Comment: There is no change :(

Comment: but in your case ajax is not even called right? `if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())` is not called and instead else part is showing. So the problem is not with the `if ($form->isValid())` right?

Comment: I pass into the first if `'$request->isXmlHttpRequest()`' otherwise I would not see my dump. (Look at the braces)